# Unable to edit alias properties in SQuirreL SQL Client Version 3.5.0?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, squirrel-sql

I'm unable to edit the properties for my DEV alias. The connection to my oracle 11g db is fine, I just need to 'trim the fat' so I don't load everything from the schema. I'm using the Oracle Thin Driver. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had this problem in 3.4.x and 3.5.x versions of SQuirrel with the Oracle plugin and JDBC Thin drivers. I don't know if it's a problem with the OCI drivers.

The problem was introduced when I updated my driver jars from version 11.2.0.3 to 11.2.0.4.

Use the Oracle 11.2.0.3 jars, and the alias properties should work again.